# Not @author but edited parts tag of java source on java docs?

Tags: java, documentation

I'm using a java class which is written by someone else but I have added my own code to that class. When Java docing do I still use `@author` tag or is a there a different one which I am supposed to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically @author is redundant information as the exact information should be present in the source repository.

When published to a web page, however, that information is usually unavailable and the @author tags provides the primary contact person(s) for that code.  If you think you should be amongst those, then put your name in.  If not, don't.

It does not fulfill a technical need, but a social need.